# What does array.prototype.includes.call(x, y) do?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am wondering what `array.prototype.includes.call(x, y);` does.

I figured out that `includes()` checks if an array contains the given value and returns true or false.

I also found out that `call()` will call `this` with optional parameters.

My problem is, that I don't get what happens here, if it's concatenated like it is here.

Comment: You pretty guy know Python? Methods on a class must hold `this` as the first argument. JavaScript's a little smarter that it knows what `this` is when running your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the explanation (from [Mozilla Developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)):

> `includes()` method is intentionally generic. It does not require this
>   value to be an Array object, so it can be applied to other kinds of
>   objects (e.g. array-like objects).
>
> The example below illustrates `includes()` method called on the
>   function's arguments object.
>
> ```
> (function() {
>   console.log(Array.prototype.includes.call(arguments, 'a'))  // true
>   console.log(Array.prototype.includes.call(arguments, 'd'))  // false
> })('a','b','c')
> ```

Array-like objects have some similarities to an `Array` (like the property `length`), but do not have functions like `map`, `slice` etc. Another array-like object is `HTMLCollection`, which you can get from `document.getElementsByTagName('div')` in the console of your browser.
You compare the results from `document.getElementsByTagName('div').__proto__` vs `[].__proto` and see getters and setters differ, but both offer `length`.

Comment: It was used wrong in my code base. That was confusing. Tank you for the explanation!